# PHP or Regex: string matches ALL characters in search pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to build a regex that will look for the occurrence of all characters in an inputted string.

For example, if the user inputs "equ" as the search parameter, "queen" and "obsequious" would match, but "qadaffi" and "tour" and "quail" would not.

Obviously I'm trying the basic /[equ]/ pattern and it's looking for "at least one of".

If there's a basic PHP function that would do this without regex, then that would be acceptable. But sad.

Comment: Why equ should match queen? Because queen contains e AND q AND u?

Answer (score 3):

`/[equ]/` is a character class which means it matches just *one* character. Try `/.*equ.*/` instead. I haven't used the php matching functions, so the `.*`'s might be unnecessary.

Edit: Apparently they're definitely unnecessary, so just use `/equ/`.

Comment: The only difference between `/.*equ.*/` and `/equ/` assuming a string matches both, is that the first will by default greedily match the entire string, while the second only matches the (first) substring `"equ"`. If all that's needed is a check for the substring, then yes, the wildcards are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

yeah, agreed that simple for loop would be more efficient in your case.

assuming `$query = "que";` and `$input = "queen";` or anything else:

```
$matched = true;
$len = strlen($query); // or mb_strlen($query) if you have multibyte string in input
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    if (!strstr($input, $query[$i])){
        $matched = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

very primitive loop to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

@sln
@jancha

I've implemented a timer to measure the speeds. Oddly, I'm finding that the regex is faster than the loop in my code. Is this right?

```
$haystack = "Obsequious";
$needle = array('e','q','u');
$regex = "/^(?=.*e)(?=.*q)(?=.*u)/";

function trial(){
    GLOBAL $haystack;
    GLOBAL $needle;
    foreach ($needle as $n) {
        if (!strpos($haystack, $n)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function trial2(){
    GLOBAL $haystack;
    GLOBAL $regex;
    if (preg_match($regex, $haystack)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

print time_trial("trial");
print time_trial("trial2");

function time_trial($function, $iterations=100000){
    $before = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$iterations ; $i++) { 
        call_user_func($function);
    }
    $after = microtime(true);
    $total = round($after-$before, 4);  
    return "Executed timed trial '$function' // $iterations iterations // $total seconds<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you try it on words that don't meet the criteria?  When I change the the test word to `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`, the regex test takes about 75% longer than the other.  That's where regexes get their reputation for slowness: failed matches can take a lot longer than successful ones--infinitely long, in some cases.

Comment: @Alan Moore That makes perfect sense. Thanks for pointing it out. So depending on the *actual content, speed will vary. In some situations regex may be better, but in others it wont.

Comment: It depends on the regex, too.  This one - `/^[^equ]*(?:(?>e()|q()|u())[^equ]*)*$\1\2\3/` - actually performs better than the `strpos` solution in the non-matching case, and *much* better when it matches.  That's because it only makes one pass over the input, and it never backtracks.  Unfortunately, ironing out the wrinkles in a regex's performance tends to have the opposite effect on its appearance. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a regex is not the tool for this job. Not a php expert, but loop through each required character checking that it exists in the object string.

Otherwise, using a regex does about the same, but its slow and overkill:

`/^(?=.*e)(?=.*q)(?=.*u)/`